# How to add Different type of language pack for whole website

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have one website, for that whole website i need to add language pack dynamically. Is there any way to do that???

I am using Laravel PHP.

Thanks in advance
Hemanth

Answer (score 0):

You should read Laravel's documentation on [Localization](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization).

Basically you will need to create folders, with the language identifier as the name, for each of your languages. Inside those folders you will create php files that returns a key-value array for translating:

```
/app
/lang
    /en
        messages.php
    /es
        messages.php
```

I suggest you create a separate php file for each of your views to keep them small. Then you need to set the locale of the app:

```
App::setLocale('es');
```

After you done those, you can access the translated string by using:

```
echo trans('messages.welcome');
```

Which will read the array in `messages.php` file in the current locale folder (if locale is set to `es` then read `/lang/es/messages.php`), and fetch the value using the key `"welcome"`.